# Spock: warning when trying to compare two BigDecimal arrays

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, spock

I'm testing my program. In particular, I need to compare two `BigDecimal` arrays:

```
def "compare two BigDecimal arrays"(){
  given:
  BigDecimal[] c = [2, 3]
  expect:
  c == [2,3] as BigDecimal[]
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA reports a warning:

```
'equals' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to '(java.math.BigDecimal[])' less... (Ctrl+F1)
```

This inspection reports assignments with incompatible types.

In *DefaultGroovyMethods* I've found following method:

```
static boolean equals(java.lang.Object[] left, java.util.List right)
```

Then, I suppose, it's okey to do:

```
def "compore BigDecimal[] and List<BigDecimal>"(){
  given:
  BigDecimal[] c = [2, 3]
  expect:
  c == [2,3]
}
```

But now following warning occurs:

```
'==' between objects of inconvertible types 'BigDecimal[]' and 'List<Integer>' less... (Ctrl+F1) 

Reports calls to .equals() and == operator usages where the target and argument are of incompatible types. While such a call might theoretically be useful, most likely it represents a bug
```

**So, my question is:** what is the right way of doing `BigDecimal[]` comparison, so that no warnings are being reported?

**Remark:** even though the warning is being reported, both test runs without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this problem occurs because IDE sees two different issues. Firstly, it refers to Java `.equals()` method when two incompatible types are being compared using `.equals()` method or `==` operator. This is the case for:

```
c == [2, 3] // BigDecimal[] == List<Integer>
```

[image]

Next, if you satisfy IDE with compatible types, then **Incompatible type assignment** check jumps in and reports warning, because IDE is smart enough to apply `DefaultGroovyMethods.equals()` alternative, but it cannot find a method that satisfies parameters `DefaultGroovyMethods.equals(BigDecimal[] a, BigDecimal[] b)`

[image]

There are at least two ways to get rid of this warning in your IDE:

**1)** You can use `DefaultGroovyMethods.equals(c, [2,3])` directly, like:

```
def "compare BigDecimal[] and List<BigDecimal> (1)"(){
    given:
    BigDecimal[] c = [2, 3]

    expect:
    DefaultGroovyMethods.equals(c, [2,3])
}
```

**2)** Or you can just suppress this warning by adding `@SuppressWarnings("GrEqualsBetweenInconvertibleTypes")` to your method (or test class if you have other methods that also generate same warning):

```
@SuppressWarnings("GrEqualsBetweenInconvertibleTypes")
def "compare BigDecimal[] and List<BigDecimal> (2)"(){
    given:
    BigDecimal[] c = [2, 3]

    expect:
    c == [2,3]
}
```

Second option allows you to use `c == [2,3]` comparison with no IDE warning, which is something you expect I guess.